# DB2 LUW: Actual full query running at certain time period

Tags: db2, db2-luw

We have a table in DB2 LUW, which gets updated at some time between 4:00 pm to 4:30 pm. However, we don't have any script running during that time. And that particular query, which run around 4:00 updates/touches the old  (year 2020) records of the table. So, we are facing 2 issues.

1. We are not aware of any script running during that time (4:00 pm to 4:30 pm).
2. We don't update any old records
   We need to find out which queries are running between 4:00 pm and 4:30 pm and touching or updating old records.
   Db2top is giving me a SQL_Statement HashValue, but i need a full query. Please let me know command which gives an actual query.

Comment: Consider setting up audit.

Comment: Check out the Activity event monitor it can be configured to capture host variables as well so you will get the full SQL statement at that point in time.

Comment: Check the scheduler(s) timeline. Don't assume the job uses dynamic SQL, it may be a compiled package A competent DBA should be able to identify what is running. That's admin work

Comment: You can add a trigger to the pre-update event that -- between 4:00 pm and 4:30 pm -- record the account that is trying to update the rows. The trigger can also force the updates to fail, so "some process somewhere" will start complaining.